# Ancestor queries produce a 503 error code in api explorer

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Running the below endpoint function with a ancestor query returns a 503 code error in the appspot api explorer while the same code works fine when run on the api explorer on a localhost devserver.

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getConferencesCreated",
           path = "getConferencesCreated",
           httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST
        )
        public List<Conference> getConferencesCreated(final User user) throws UnauthorizedException {
            if (user == null) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException("Authorization required");
            }
            String userId = user.getUserId();
            Key<Profile> userKey = Key.create(Profile.class, userId);
            return ofy().load().type(Conference.class)
                    .ancestor(userKey)
                    .order("name").list();
    }
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the app logs for the event?

Comment: I was getting a 503 error.   {
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "backendError",
"message": "Backend Error"
}
],
"code": 503,
"message": "Backend Error"
}
}...Now it works fine..must be something with the google's backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine now. The problem was that the indexes required for querying were not prepared yet thus giving a 503 error. Running the query function in localhost will start the indexing process in the google's backend and your function will work fine after indexes are prepared.